# Image Map jumps to origin when hot spot selected

Tags: html, css

I have a very large panoramic image of my old school onto which I am using a combination of images maps and  tooltips (using Tooltipster) to tag faces and to get feedback for suggested names.  My problem is that when I select a face which is off the screen (i.e. I had to scroll to get to it) as soon as I click the hop spot, the image jumps to its origin (top left corner) and the person I selected and the tooltip are off the screen and not visible.

You can see a demo of this here:  http://www.oldkingstonianshull.org.uk/members/slider_demo/panorama_1925.html  Only the people at the extreme ends of the photo have hot spots for this demo.

Is there a way to prevent the jump to the origin?  I am not a programmer so need basic guidance on how to do this if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: We can't view the link without authorisation :)

Comment: Ah yes - sorry I will remove the authentication now - doh!

Comment: I can't see the page without auth, but i guess it's an href="#" problem. Doese the page url get a "#" added at the same time it bugs ? If yes, please make sure your onclick event returns false.
href="#" onclick="makeMyTooltip(); return false;"

Comment: Still cannot connect

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Okay no problem I got it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because you're pointing to #, notice that # appears after your URI upon click.

Ensure your javascript returns false after functionality has occured and this functionality should be prevented.

```
//do something
return false;

onclick="... return false;"
```

This will stop the jump to the top of the page where it tries to point to an undefined tag.

Alternatively with jquery...

```
$(".face").click(function(e) {
    function();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I see you're using tooltipster, which casts event on click, meaning that you're not actually linking anything, so I'm not sure where you would disable this functionality - I'll take a further look.

Comment: Thank you Jack.  I will look at this solution later today.

Comment: No problem, would be cool to see working! My granddad went to this school so is probably on these pictures haha